# how to make public JSON in web application using java

Tags: java, json, google-app-engine, web

I'm beginner in web application development(Google AppEngine) 
I want to show my data in JSON like below link

http://api.androidhive.info/contacts/[JSON](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/json/json_java_example.htm)

I'm following this link

[tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/json/json_java_example.htm)

but I don't know how to show data in web URL. Please provide any tutorials or any example to do this using Google App Engine.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a bit vague.
What frameworks / libraries are you using or do you need guidance on that as well?

Here is one [tutorial](http://www.planetjones.co.uk/blog/19-05-2013/google-app-engine-endpoints-with-java-maven-part1.html) for GAE you could follow which also has the code available on [Github](https://github.com/planetjones/PlanetJones/tree/master/test-blood-pressure-monitor).

Answer (score 0):

You can build a REST service. :) just like here -> http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/rest/jersey/json-example-with-jersey-jackson/